# What is the name of the function $G(z)=E[X|X\geq z] P(X\geq z)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, soft-question

Take some real valued continuous random variable $X$ with CDF $F$. Take a function $G:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as

$$G(z)=\int^\infty_z xdF(x)=\mathbb{E}[X|X\geq z]
\mathbb{P}(X\geq z).$$

Does $G$ have a name? 
Apologies if this is not an appropriate question for this site but I don't want to make up a name for it if there is a known nomenclature for it.

Comment: It has been called "life expectancy" in some contexts, but I don't know if this term is widely used by mathematicians.

Comment: Isn't it just the conditional expectation as you identified, $E[X|X>z]$?